# Booting Win7 from flash on a machine with dual boot

Tags: windows-7, usb, installation, multi-boot

I wanted to re-install Windows 7 and created a bootable USB (using command prompt  I restarted my PC and selected primary boot device as USB-HDD (my BIOS also gives options USB-ZIP USB-CDROM and USB-FDD) but it went straight to usual boot. That it to dual boot screen. I thought maybe I chose wrong boot device in BIOS I tired all other options with no luck.
Finally I formatted the USB and used [Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool](http://wudt.codeplex.com/) to create a bootable USB. That have not fixed the issue.

I have one idea why I cant boot from flash. I have a dual boot (Win7/Ubuntu) on my machine. That could inter fear with PC`s booting process.

If you have any idea how to fix it or have meet similar problems please share your knowledge.

Comment: Did you run the *setup.exe* that you get when you download that tool?  It looks like you have to run that first to extract the boot.wim file properly to a formatted (FAT32) flash drive.

Comment: I used wrong formating for my flash thou it is still strange that installation was affected.

Answer (score 0):

The either of the following links would guide you to format your flashdrive in the optimum way

[Link 1](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/)

[Link 2](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-bootable-windows-7-usb-to-install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive-using-windows-7-dvdusb-tool/)

Comment: Neither of them helped....